# Get the top 10% of records based on score column

Tags: oracle, top-n

I have a SCORE column. How do I select the top 10% from EMPLOYEE table with top scores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with [analytics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407). Assuming that score is ascending (higher scores are better):

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM (SELECT e.*,
               row_number() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC)
               / COUNT(*) OVER () pct
          FROM employee e) e
 WHERE pct <= 0.1
```

This will select at most 10% of your employees. If there are equal scores among them, the above SQL will pick among them in a non-deterministic fashion. If you want to include all those that are in the top 10% including duplicate scores, replace [`row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#i86310) by [`rank()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions141.htm#i1269223).

You could also use the [`NTILE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions115.htm#i85619) function:

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM (SELECT e.*,
               ntile(10) OVER (order by score DESC) ntile#
          FROM employee e) e
 WHERE ntile# = 1
```

Comment: Vincent - Awesome! I want to include all those that are in top 10% so I will use rank()